# Limits and Derivatives of Summation

Tags: limits, derivatives

Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n \in (0,1)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i = 1$ Let $\beta \ge 0, \beta \ne 1$ define,
$F(\beta)=\frac{1}{1-\beta}\text{log}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{\beta}).$

a) Calculate: $\lim \limits_{\beta \to 1} F(\beta)$

b) Show: $\frac{dF(\beta)}{d\beta} = \frac{1}{(1-\beta)^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}\text{log}(\frac{p_i}{z_i})$   where $z_i = \frac{p_{i}^\beta}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^\beta}$

**My Work:** I took $n=2$ and $n=3$ to observe a pattern and saw that $p_1=p_2=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p_1=p_2=p_3=\frac{1}{3}$ came respectively. This led me to think that maybe we can write $\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i$ as $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$(n times).

Help of any kind is welcome.

**Edit: I tried doing this,**

$\because p_i \in (0,1), \therefore p_{i}^{\beta} < p_i$
$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}^{\beta}< \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}$
Taking log both sides,
$\implies \text{log}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}^{\beta})<\text{log}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i})$
$\implies \lim \limits_{\beta \to 1} \frac{1}{1-\beta}\text{log}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{\beta}) < 0$

Comment: Have you tried some examples, like $n=2$ $p_1=p_2=1/2$ to figure out what is happening ? Can you do it if not? Update your question with such elements if yes?

Comment: Yes, I did for $n=2$ and $n=3$ which gave me $p_1=p_2=1/2$ and $p_1=p_2=p_3=1/3$. That led me to think that maybe we can write $p_i$ as $1/n$? But that's all I came up with.

Comment: Please update your question with those elements.

Comment: Done @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry, I should've written that part.

Comment: Your update is saying nothing about the limit in that case... I meant update with relevant information.

Comment: Because I have no clue as to how to approach it in anyway. This all that I had thought of.

Comment: As stated, the $p_i$ are given quantities ... how can $p_1=p_2=p_3$ be an "outcome"? Look carefully at what you are being asked to show.

Comment: @Greg Martin if you'd see my edit now and maybe comment. I am actually having difficulties doing this sum.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, does my work have any insight now? Please help.